# Limit a Value from Array in MQL4

Tags: arrays, mql4

How to limit the output which has results between some range values, for example: 240 < outputvalue < 250.

Anyone have an example please? I am trying with this code, but give no result:

```
int NumberOfHighs = 1;
double outputvalue;

for (int i=0; i<BarsLimit; i++)
{
    int totals[];
    ArrayInitialize(totals, 0);

    datetime StartTime=iTime(NULL, 0, i);
    int startShift = iBarShift(NULL, 0, StartTime, false);

    outputvalue = get_value(startShift, SOMEINPUT, SOMEINPUT);
    totals[outputvalue]++;

    if (outputvalue>=240.0 && outputvalue<250.0 && totals[outputvalue]<NumberOfHighs)
    {
         Print("StartTime; ", TimeToString(StartTime, TIME_DATE), " outputvalue: ", outputvalue);
         ........
    }
}
```

The result so far can see on: [image]
Can someone help me, would really appreciate it. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: and what is the problem here? you compute `outputvalue` and then check it to be inside your range. if you need to update your value (so if it is 239.99 - let it be 240) then use something like `outputvalue=fmin(250,fmax(240,outputvalue));`

Comment: @pije Yes, please clarify your question and tell us what your current and expected output should be.